# pyspark kernel on Jupyter generates "spark not found" error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have a few `pyspark` kernel `jupyter` notebooks that had been working for months - but recently are working no longer. The `pyspark` kernel itself is working: it gives blue message:

```
    Kernel Loaded
```

..  and we can see the kernel is *available*:

[image]

But I noticed this in the `jupyter` log:

> [IPKernelApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling PYTHONSTARTUP file /shared/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py:

And  when attempting to do some work in `spark` we get:

```
---> 18     df = spark.read.parquet(path)
     19     if count: p(tname + ": count="+str(df.count()))
     20     df.createOrReplaceTempView(tname)

NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

with no further information.

Note: the `scala` spark kernel using `toree` is able to read that same file through parquet successfully (and using the same code actually)

So what might be going on with the `jupyter pyspark` kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  I had upgraded `spark` and the `pyspark` kernel did not know about it.

First: which `kernels` are installed:

```
$jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
  python2        /Users/sboesch/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  ir             /Users/sboesch/Library/Jupyter/kernels/ir
  julia-1.0      /Users/sboesch/Library/Jupyter/kernels/julia-1.0
  scala          /Users/sboesch/Library/Jupyter/kernels/scala
  scijava        /Users/sboesch/Library/Jupyter/kernels/scijava
  pyspark        /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark
  spark_scala    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/spark_scala
```

Let's examine the `pyspark` kernel:

```
sudo vim  /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json
```

Of particular interest is the `spark` jar file:

```
PYTHONPATH="/shared/spark/python/:/shared/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip"
```

Is it available?

```
$ll "/shared/spark/python/:/shared/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip"
ls: /shared/spark/python/:/shared/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip: No such file or directory
```

No it is not - so let's update that path:

```
 $ll /shared/spark/python/lib/py4j*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 sboesch  wheel  42437 Jun  1 13:49 /shared/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip


PYTHONPATH="/shared/spark/python/:/shared/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip"
```

After this I restarted `jupyter` and the `pyspark` kernel is working.